# Can a theme name be started with a number?

Tags: 7, theming

Can I start a theme name with a number? For example: "123go"

Does Drupal recognize folders & files that start with it?

Does it work in the temple.php as the start of a function?

Comment: oh, got it-  "A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

That answers that question. Don't start a theme name with a number because it can't be used as a function in template.php

Comment: I suggest you write that down as an answer (answering your own question is perfectly legit!) and accept it, so that the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: yep, just had to wait a few hours to have the permission to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh, got it- "A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."

php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

That answers that question. Don't start a theme name with a number because it can't be used as a function in template.php